# What neis hapenned to Baal Shem Tov on Achron shel Pesach?

Tags: passover, miracle, hasidic-story, baal-shem-tov

I have heard a special miracle is commemorated at Seudas HaBesh"t (third meal) on the last day of Pesach. What hapenned to Baal Shem Tov on Achron shel Pesach?

Comment: Your editing in any info about where you heard this may help people find the answer to your question.

Comment: Are you referencing the story where he stopped over in Turkey in his way to Israel?

Comment: @mroll - that story was the night of the first seder

Comment: @Menachem That (mrolls suggestion) sounds familiar. It was something that involved the minhag to eat kneildlach on the last day. I heard that the story has many versions.  I don't really think i remember details clearly enough to put them in question

Comment: Are you maybe referring to this?  https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3316167/jewish/22-Nissan.htm

Comment: Is this about Judaism, or just Jews?

Comment: A chassidic custom to celebrate a miracle that happened to a Jewish leader seems like a question about Judaism to me.

Comment: @user18660 I don't see any miracle story there

Comment: I heard today the version of Nittei Gavriel. He wanted to go to Palestine to jon Ohr Hachaim Hakadosh and bring Moshich. He stopped in Istanbul, Turkey and spent a long time singing "leoseh niflaos lvado" at the Seder, because the Sultan's minister, who had insinuated a blood libel against the Jews, had been discovered to be a Christian and thwarted. This sounds like what you referring to @Menachem. But there is more..

Comment: @mroll ..On chol hamoed he set out to Eretz Yisroel, and on the last day of Pesach he was ship wrecked on an island and cannibals came to eat him. The assistant of the Besh''t told him to speak learning for protection, but the Rabbi forgot his learning. Instead they said Aleph Bet, and police came and saved them. To commemorate the miracle hasidim celebrate Seudat HaBesht on the last day of Pesach. There also is apparently different version of the story from Avner Gold, direct descendant of Baal Shem Tov, perhaps involving Matzo-balls. Details welcome!